# How do I get the man page for "apt upgrade"?

Tags: command-line, apt, man

Getting the man page for *apt* is simple: `man apt`

The problem is, *apt* has several "sub commands" (such as `update`, `install`, `remove`), all with their own arguments and settings. These arguments and options aren't listed in *apt*'s man page.

How do I get more details for a command like `apt upgrade`?

Answer (score 2):

You should run the following command:

```
man apt-get
```

eg:

```
upgrade
       upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in /etc/apt/sources.list.
       Packages currently installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or
       packages not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the install
       status of another package will be left at their current version. An update must be performed first so that apt-get knows that new versions of packages
       are available.
```